# Is "well" an adjective or an adverb in "I am well"?

Tags: grammar

Is "well" an adjective or an adverb in the sentence"I am well"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the question is as simple as it looks at first glance, it's an adjective : "*I* am well", where "well" describes the condition of the speaker [noun].

If it's a bit more existential (and probably done by someone trying to be clever), in "*I am*, well" - meaning that the speaker is competent at the act of existing - it could be an adverb where "well" describes the quality with which the speaker is undertaking the act of being [verb].

The second interpretation is unlikely, and a bit of a stretch if the phrase appears as written in the question. Any writer worth spit would have highlighted it by showing emphasis and/or context if they had meant that.

Comment: I didn't understand your second point.

Comment: @NSR - Then it's probably not that : my second point was more an intellectual exercise in whether it could have been an adverb (eg. "How are you doing?"). Thanks for the upvote - probably worth holding off marking an answer as  accepted this early, though - there might be something better along in a few hours.

Comment: I understood your second point with this example: "I am here".